# How do I change the code convention in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, coding-style, formatter

I like to use curly brackets in this fashion

```
void hello()
{
    code();
}
```

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> in Eclipse it changes everything to

```
void hello(){
    code();
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Window/Preferences/Java/Code style/Formatter view:

Create a new profile based on the eclipse built in, then go to braces tab and change "same line" to next line everywhere. Then set the new profile to default.

Answer (score 4):

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Braces

Answer (score 2):

Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter

Comment: Wrong, wrong. It's the *Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter*.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, go to Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Formatter.
Choose the Formatter you have. Click on Edit...  Go to Tab "Braces".  Change as suitable.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, go to 
Windows -> Preference -> Java -> Formatter.
In Active Profile drop down box, select any profile, click Edit on right of it.
In Profile Dialog box opened, you can change a lot of things like Indentation, New Line, Braces, White Spaces etc.
Alternatively, if your profile is altogether different than standard one, Create a new active profile and then edit it accordingly.

:)